# Удаление в Weakmap

Tags: javascript

Прочитав про WeakMap наткнулся на следующую фразу:

"Если мы используем объект в качестве ключа и если больше нет ссылок на этот объект,

то он будет удалён из памяти (и из объекта WeakMap) автоматически."

**Но у меня есть ссылка на объект-ключ, почему же сборщик мусора удаляет мой объект-ключ?**

```js
let weakmap = new WeakMap();

let obj = {};

weakmap.set(obj,'ok');

obj = null;    

let xopa = obj; // Ссылка на объект-ключ

alert(weakmap.get(obj));
```

Comment: что тут происходит `let xopa = obj;` ? и для чего это строка?

Comment: вас интересует почему undefined после того как вы написали `obj = null;` ?

Comment: let xopa = obj это ссылка на объект, а когда есть ссылка, то объект не должен удаляться. Так было сказано в учебнике. Но у меня объект удалился и я хочу понять почему.

Comment: "то объект не должен удаляться." ---- а какой объект у вас удалился? ..........."let xopa = obj это ссылка на объект" ---- а вот это `obj = null;` вам ни о чём не говорит?))

Comment: Даже более того, строчку `obj = null;` можно заменить на `obj = {};` с тем же самым результатом.

Comment: @Yaant по-моему это разные вещи. obj = null затирает ссылку на объект, а obj = {} - создает новый пустой.

Comment: @BearVorkuta Вещи, конечно, разные, но в контексте вопроса эта разница роли не играет :)

Comment: @Yaant просто автор вопроса и так запутался со ссылками на объекты и самими объектами, поэтому чтобы не было большей путаницы - уточнил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы уничтожаете объект `obj = null;` до присваивания его в переменную `xopa` да и в строке `weakmap.get(obj)` пользуетесь не тем объектом..... логично, что результат такой

```js
let weakmap = new WeakMap();

let obj = {};

weakmap.set(obj,'ok');



let xopa = obj; // Ссылка на объект-ключ
obj = null;    
alert(weakmap.get(xopa));
```

Comment: Таким образом obj  остается в памяти? Его не удаляет сборщик мусора?

Comment: Удалён будет как только `obj = null;`