# Удаленный ключ в WeakMap

Tags: javascript

Изучав тему Weakmap, наткнулся на строку:

"Теперь john существует только как ключ в WeakMap и может быть удалён оттуда автоматически."

Но у меня ключ **в виде johh** не существует в WeakMap, он удалился оттуда.

**alert выдает false** при попытке вызвать **ключ john ,** но почему, если  **ключ john**
должен сохраниться согласно этому учебнику: https://learn.javascript.ru/weakmap-weakset

```js
let john = {};

let weakmap = new WeakMap();
weakmap.set(john,'');

john = null;

alert(weakmap.has(john));  // Выдает false, значит ключ john не сохранился
```

Comment: ключом является сам объект, а во второй проверке, ты проверяешь ключ `null`

Comment: Не могли бы вы на примере кода это продемонстрировать?

Comment: продемонстрировать что?

Comment: @Grundy а какая разница что он там проверяет, ключа уже все равно нет

Comment: @Grundy я понял (после этого вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1255199/191482 и комментариев ,а также текущего), что у автора возникло непонимание и конфуз того, что именно удаляет сборщик и с чем работает код так скажем. То есть ему кажется что удаляется сам obj как переменная из кода, а не то, куда он указывает и где лежит/не лежит объект/ссылки.

Comment: Я где-то недавно видел чистое разжёванное это объяснение. Но не помню у кого....Наверное надо какой-то отдельный вопрос по объектам, переменным и памяти задать, может как дубль закроют как раз ссылкой на него :))) Другого выхода найти не вижу)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, вы хотите сказать, что удаляется ссылка на объект, а не сам объект?

Answer (score -1):

```
let john = {};
let weakmap = new WeakMap();
```

здесь вы передаете не сам объект, а ссылку на него

```
  weakmap.set(john,'');
```

Ниже аналогичная ситуация

```
console.log(weakmap.has(john)); //выведет true, потому как передали верную ссылку

john = null;

console.log(weakmap.has(john)); //выведет false, так как ссылка нулевая, weakmap не нашел объект по этой ссылке
```

если в консоли после этого вывести `weakmap`, то увидите, что ключ в виде объекта на месте

P.S. хотя судя по логике "WeakMap" - объект должен удалиться из памяти. И как ключ в weakmap тоже )))